# Projects on Memory Paging

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

i am studying for a test on operating systems , and i would love it if i can take a look at
free source projects regarding memory management and memory paging.

Thanks very much for your help:)

Nataly

Comment: Linux? (Stupid character minimum.)

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of OS kernels with source available, but I have a feeling trying to pick through them is going to be very difficult.  A production kernel is a complex piece of work, so it's hard to understand the theory behind it by looking at the code.

What you probably want is an OS simulator that focuses on teaching the theory.  We wrote our own in my OS classes.  Just a quick google search came up with this list of a number of them:

http://vip.cs.utsa.edu/simulators/